# Sequelize - [SequelizeDatabaseError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update]

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a 15 part promise chain that is a part of a Sequelize transaction. The premise of the chain is to delete all of my table records when a user takes an action to delete their account. Before all of the table records are deleted, I am storing the length of their objects to be able to have a record of the account being deleted and the quantity of records that was previously associated with each table. In my current setup I'm making it through the table, but running into the following error at the `.create` method for creating the record for the deleted account.

```
Transaction Error
[SequelizeDatabaseError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update]
```

When I run the executed SQL query in my postgres account, I have no problem, which indicates that the SQL generated by Sequelize is correct, but another problem is the issue.

```
Executing (35807900-1fe0-4676-b132-877a32307385): INSERT INTO "test_account" ("test_account_id","account_id","document_quantity","document_report_quantity","category_quantity","user_quantity","updated_at","created_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,51,1,0,2,2,'2017-07-16 23:12:03.180 +00:00','2017-07-16 23:12:03.180 +00:00') RETURNING *;
```

Can anyone tell me what this means and why it is happening when this piece of code is triggered?

**There is one association between `test_account` and `account`:**

```
classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            TestAccount.belongsTo(db.Account, { foreignKey: 'account_id' });
        }
    }
```

**Here is the chain:**

```
return models.sequelize.transaction().then(function(t){
    //STEP 1: Query Documents
    return deleteAccount.queryAllDocuments(req.session.organizationId, t)
    .then(function(_document){
        documents = _document;
        documentsArr = documents;
        documentsLength = documents.length;
    })
    //STEP 2: Cancel Stripe Account
    .then(() => deleteAccount.cancelStripeAccount(req.session.subscriptionId))
    .then(function(_canceledStripeAccount){
        canceledStripeAccount = _canceledStripeAccount;
        canceledAt = canceledStripeAccount.canceled_at;
    })
    //STEP 3: Update Account Record
    .then(() => deleteAccount.updateAccountCancelDate(canceledAt, canceledStripeAccount, t))
    //STEP 4: Query Account Record
    .then(() => deleteAccount.queryAccount(req.session.subscriptionId, t))
    .then(function(_account){
        accountId = _account.accountId;
    })
    //STEP 5: Create Delete Account Record
    .then(() => deleteAccount.createDeletedAccountRecord(accountId, req.session.organizationId, canceledAt, t))
    .then(function(_deletedAccount){
        deletedAccount = _deletedAccount;
    })
    //STEP 6: Query All Document Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.queryAllDocumentReports(documentsArr, t))
    .then(function(_documentsReports){
        documentsReports = _documentsReports.length;
    })
    //STEP 7: Delete All Document File Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.deleteDocumentFiles(documentsArr, req.session.organizationId, documentsFiles, t))
    //STEP 8: Delete All Document Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.deleteDocuments(documentsArr, t))
    //STEP 9: Query All Category Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.queryAllCategories(req.session.organizationId, t))
    .then(function(_categories){
        categories = _categories.length;
    })
    //STEP 10: Delete All Category Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.deleteCategories(req.session.organizationId, t))
    //STEP 11: Query All User Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.queryUsers(req.session.organizationId, t))
    .then(function(_users){
        users = _users.length;
        usersArr = components.usersRecordId(_users);
    })
    //STEP 12: Query Account Record
    .then(() => deleteAccount.queryAccount(req.session.subscriptionId, t))
    .then(function(_account){
        accountId = _account.accountId;
    })
    //STEP 13: Update Deleted Account Record ////////THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR TRANSACTION ERROR OCCURS
    .then(() => deleteAccount.createTestAccount(accountId, documentsLength, documentsReports, categories, users, t))
    //STEP 14: Deleted Organization Record
    .then(() => deleteAccount.deleteOrganization(req.session.organizationId, t))
    //STEP 15: Delete All User Records
    .then(() => deleteAccount.deleteUsers(usersArr, t))
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Account Deleted Successfully");
        t.commit();
    });
    }).then(function(){
        req.session.destroy();
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Transaction Error");
    console.log(err);
});
```